# Flutter & Dart & Telegram Bot : How do I send a message with any keyword into my telegram bot?

Tags: flutter, dart, message, telegram-bot

How I keep send message to my telegram bot with any keyword or entity? In other word, How do I send a message from my app to telegram bot?

```
    var teledart = TeleDart(
        Telegram('MY TOKEN'),
        Event());
    teledart.start().then(
        (me) => print('${me.username} ${me.id} is initialised'));



    teledart
        .onMessage(keyword: 'BTC')
        .listen((message) => message.reply('Stand with Hong Kong'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
var telegram = Telegram('token_Bot');
var teledart = TeleDart(telegram, Event());

teledart.start().then((me) => print('${me.username} is initialised'));

teledart.onMessage(entityType: 'bot_command', keyword: 'start')
     .listen((message) => teledart.telegram.sendMessage(message.chat.id, message.chat.id.toString()));
```

With the command above whenever someone sends to bot /start he will respond with an id, through this id it is possible to send messages to that person or group with this send command.

```dart
teledart.telegram.sendMessage('id_telegram_recebido', 'hi!');
```

By making a request at 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<token_bot>/getUpdates' you can get all messages sent in groups with '/' recent and any messages from recent private conversations.